# CSS responding slowly

Tags: css

i am having a very weird problem, my CSS is responding very slowly. When i click on a button, it switches the z-index to 500 instead of -999; i can see in console (chrome) that the value has been changed. However it takes 2-3 seconds for it to show up.

When i resize the window i see a white space showing up (the additional space) and it takes a few seconds again until it adapts to the new size.

What can be creating this issue? I am especially confused as simple things as adapting the size to the current screen width (in CSS i used width: 100%) doesnt work quickly.

is there any way which i can do to check what is going on in the browser?

It might help to notice that this error is happening randomly, sometimes it all works flawlessly, sometimes it takes forever.

Im really helpless :(

Comment: You need to edit your question and add a [mcve]

Comment: its difficult to create an example, i have over 20,000 lines of code. when i take a piece out of it, it will not show the effects anymore

Comment: Ah but yes–that's precisely the type of problem-solving technique you could employ! Remove all extraneous code until you have reached the lowest common denominator so that you can identity where your problem code actually lies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a sprite sheet that was too big - apparently resizing and displaying the single elements was taking the additional time.

Using a smaller sprite sheet makes everything work again flawlessly